# Have a cell report weather for specific date in google sheets

Tags: api, google-sheets, formula, weather

Hello trying to create a sheet where A1 contains a date B1 Contains a zipcode and C1 reports the temp for said zipcode on the date in A1. I have tried the following

`=Query(IMPORTHTML("https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/@z-us-"&A1&"/ext","table",1),"SELECT Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col8 WHERE Col1='"&TEXT(B1,"ddd MMM DD YYYY")&"'", 2)`

But sadly I cant get it to work. Would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `IMPORTHTML()` function is working on it’s own first?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like TimeAndDate.com does not allow programmatic access via the `IMPORTHTML()` function.

As you can see below, even attempting to pull a hard-coded URL that we’ve confirmed is valid we still get the `“Could not fetch url:…` error.

[image]